# Regular expression in ruby to match the text between first occurrence and last occurrence of a character

Tags: ruby, regex

Can anyone help me to form a regular expression in ruby that would match the text between first occurrence and last occurrence of a character.

For example, for the character `-`:

**ruby-on-rails** should get result --> ***on***

**abc-def-ghi-jkl** should get result --> ***def-ghi***

**mnop-qrst-uvw-xyza-bc-defg-hij-123** should get result --> ***qrst-uvw-xyza-bc-defg-hij***

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: -1 The question is totally unclear. The text between the first occurrence and [the] last occurrence of a character (`r`) in `ruby-on-rails` is `uby-on-`. How does it become `on`?

Comment: I'm usually reluctant to edit questions, preferring instead to leave comments, but this is an example where an edit is called for, as the intent was pretty clear from the examples, yet the asker could be absent for some time.  Thanks, @Uri.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This very simple regex will do (because the `*` operator is greedy by default):

```
/-(.*)-/
```

http://regex101.com/r/yZ7rI5

In ruby:

```
'ruby-on-rails'[/-(.*)-/, 1]
# => "on" 
'abc-def-ghi-jkl'[/-(.*)-/, 1]
# => "def-ghi"
'mnop-qrst-uvw-xyza-bc-defg-hij-123'[/-(.*)-/, 1]
# => "qrst-uvw-xyza-bc-defg-hij"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'ruby-on-rails'.scan(/-(.*)-/).first.first
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
result = subject.scan(/-(.*)-/)
```